# Roblox Leaderboard Statues being downsized upon load

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a map on my game where the top 3 people on the leaderboard load in, the problem is that you go from be super big to super small

How would I fix this?

```lua
while true do
    if game.ReplicatedStorage.LeaderboardValues.ThirdPlace.UID.Value ~= 0 then -- This is only for 3rd place
        local Playerdesc = game.Players:GetHumanoidDescriptionFromUserId(game.ReplicatedStorage.LeaderboardValues.ThirdPlace.UID.Value)
        script.Parent.Humanoid:ApplyDescription(Playerdesc)
        wait(7)
    end
    wait(3)

end
```

[image: After]
[image: After]

Comment: I should've uploaded the right image first, but Left is After, and Right is Before

Comment: Seems like this is a common issue on the DevForums. [Thread 1](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/how-would-i-properly-scale-hats-loaded-from-humanoid-description/1928010), [Thread 2](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/applydescription-is-changing-npc-scale/1161446)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to preserve the proportions of the original Dummy, but I have found that a simple work-around could be to take the HumanoidDescription and mess with the scaling before applying it to the Dummy.  With some trial and error, you might be able to get something that *looks* close enough.

```lua
-- grab references to the humanoid descriptions and the rig we'll be applying it to
local description = game.Workspace.HumanoidDescription
local dummy = game.Workspace.Dummy

-- grab the original position of the dummy
local originalPosition = dummy.PrimaryPart.CFrame.Position

-- mess with the scaling of the description
local scaleFactor = 3
description.BodyTypeScale *= scaleFactor
description.DepthScale *= scaleFactor
description.HeadScale *= scaleFactor
description.HeightScale *= scaleFactor
description.ProportionScale *= scaleFactor
description.WidthScale *= scaleFactor

-- apply the description
dummy.Humanoid:ApplyDescription(description)

-- move the dummy back to its original position so that the physics engine will place the feet properly on the floor
dummy:MoveTo(originalPosition)
```

| Original | Applied Description |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |